# How to read email using Python 3

Tags: python, email, decode, imaplib

Now I am here

```
 import imaplib
 mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
 mail.login('login@gmail.com', 'password')
 mail.list()
 # Out: list of "folders" aka labels in gmail.
 mail.select("inbox") # connect to inbox.
 #Get an email
 result, data = mail.uid('fetch', b'1', '(RFC822)')
    raw_email = data[0][1]
    email_message = email.message_from_bytes(raw_email)
    maintype = email_message.get_content_maintype()
    #HERE COMES TROUBLES - if hmtl will be base64 string
    if maintype == 'multipart':
        for part in email_message.get_payload():
            print(part.get_content_maintype())
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'text':
                html = str(part.get_payload())
    elif maintype == 'text':
        html = str(email_message.get_payload())

    #Now I Can parse HTML
    if html is not None:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

some letters come with base64 coding. how decode it?
base64.b64encode(some_string) - doesn't help

Comment: raw_email = data[0][1].. you were almost there.https://yuji.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/python-imaplib-imap-example-with-gmail/

Comment: Thanks! I was starting from that tutorial. But I think I get bytes string so its a little bit different. Can you show me final code?

Comment: Can you paste what it is outputting from raw_email? Add this line to the end of your script ......print(raw_email)

Comment: I started understand, but how does  .get_payload() work in easy words?

Comment: email.get_payload() returns a List of Message Objects https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message

Comment: I posted your solution down below. Please accept if it worked for you so other users with your problem can use.

Comment: Yes it works! Now Problem is that part.get_payload() - looks like: /XLCDe1M8g0M/a18/M0cXUIMnawsXWwdTYCs7Fz8LIz8TJzc/T1Mkg19nCz9LBIM/Ezs/ etc. If I get it it is a base64 string? How can I decode to html?

Comment: In your original post can you paste what your currently seeing on your console?

Comment: Do you mean how data looks?

Comment: It should be read fine from .get_payload. Can you paste your new code at the top?

Comment: Done! base64 string too long too paste here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import email

raw_email = data[0][1]
email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email)

print email_message['To']

print email.utils.parseaddr(email_message['From']) # for parsing "Yuji Tomita" <yuji@grovemade.com>

print email_message.items() # print all headers


def get_first_text_block(self, email_message_instance):
maintype = email_message_instance.get_content_maintype()
if maintype == 'multipart':
    for part in email_message_instance.get_payload():
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'text':
            return part.get_payload()
elif maintype == 'text':
    return email_message_instance.get_payload()
```

**I did not write this taken from https://yuji.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/python-imaplib-imap-example-with-gmail/