# Is it possible to scrape mails within hotmail using Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, screen-scraping, hotmail

Can this actually be done? Like checking if my browser is logged in and if so, scraw some of my emails? Or does hotmail prevent you from scraping your mails?

Comment: It would be a huge pain in the butt. Just retrieve your emails through POP or IMAP

Comment: I actually want to find out if it's possible to have a website that visits hotmail on the background using python and scrape some data if the current client is logged in. I don't have any blackhat intentions, just curious.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287490/is-there-a-way-to-use-phantomjs-in-python

Comment: Take a look at that answer. There are a bunch of technologies for controlling a browser instance through python.

Answer (score 0):

Yes actually very easily.
All you have to do is connect to a POP or IMAP(gmail,hotmail) and then manipulate data however you want.`import smtplib`
[Here's a link documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_sending_email.htm)  --- [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31703739/how-to-read-email-using-python-3) 
 --- [POP -email](http://www.codemiles.com/python-tutorials/reading-email-in-python-t10271.html) ---  [Gmail](https://gist.github.com/robulouski/7441883) 
You can use regular expressions if you want to find something specific 
[Python RE-Regular Expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

I don't know how would you check if you're already logged in, there isn't an obvious way to tell.
Of course it could be done but in some weird manner.

Comment: That's not web-scraping though

Comment: I actually want to find out if it's possible to have a website that visits hotmail on the background using python and scrape some data if the current client is logged in. I don't have any blackhat intentions, just curious.

Comment: Well that's true :)

Comment: Yeah, that's a much easier task(I think) making a google chrome extension would be perfect.

Comment: You don't use SMTP to retrieve mails, that's for sending. Either you use POP or IMAP.